# Задача на Delphi

Tags: delphi, алгоритм, pascal

> Сведения о деталях, хранящихся на складе, содержат следующие атрибуты:
>   название, количество, стоимость одной детали. Составить программу
>   решающие следующие задачи:
>
> 1. Вычислить общую стоимость детали.
> 2. Вычислить какие детали имеются в наибольшем количестве и какие в
>      наименьшем.
> 3. Вывести информацию о наличии на складе детали одного типа и её
>      количества.

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить такую задачу для Console Application (Delphi)
Набросал кое-что, но не получилось

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type detal = record
a: string[30];
kol, st: integer; end;

var a: array [0..99] of detal; n, i, max: integer;

begin
  { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
  write('Kollichestvo detaley ');
  readln(n);
 for i:=0 to n-1 do

 With a[i] do
begin write('informacia ob ', i, ' detali: ');
   readln(a);
   readln(kol);
   readln(st);
 end;
 max := 0;
 for i:= 1 to n-1 do
  if a[max].kol*a[max].st < a[i].kol*a[i].st then max:=i;
 writeln('iskoma9 detal: ',  a[max].a, ' stoimostiu ', a[max].st, ' v kolichestve ', a[max].kol);
end.
```

Comment: Ответ не выдает у меня она, ошибки выскакивают

Comment: Какие?

Comment: Уже нет ошибок (перезапустил delphi), но зато повторяется действие 'информация о детали' и закрывается само окно программы.

Comment: Правильно ли сама программа вообще написана ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
begin
{ TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
write('Kolichestvo detaley ');
readln(n);

for i:=0 to n-1 do
  begin
  write('informacia ob ', i, ' detali: ');
  readln(a[i].a);
  readln(a[i].kol);
  readln(a[i].st);
  end;

max := 0;
for i:= 1 to n-1 do
  if a[max].kol*a[max].st < a[i].kol*a[i].st then
    max:=i;
writeln('iskoma9 detal: ',  a[max].a, ' stoimostiu ', a[max].st, ' v kolichestve ', a[max].kol);
readln;
end;
```

Попоробуйте так

Comment: Спасибо заработало _)

Comment: @Slepoi_kot, чтобы принять ответ как верный, нажмите галку слева от ответа. Не за что)